# What is this hole on the left wing of the Eurofighter Typhoon?

Tags: military, wing, fighter, feature-identification, eurofighter-typhoon

I came across the picture below and saw the hole near the centerline on the left which appears to have some carbon next to it. What is its purpose and where does the carbon come from?

[image]

Comment: Cartridge starter?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### The Auxiliary Power Unit (APU) exhaust

[image]
([Source](http://www.f-16.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=5525&start=1185&hilit=Osley&sid=c776efebbce64c5ae6430765e940908d))

The item **72** is what you are looking for and it is labelled "APU exhaust". The black residue is soot from incompletely burned fuel.

The Eurofighter Typhoon can use its APU to start the main engine or to provide power when on the ground. From [airvectors.net](http://www.airvectors.net/aveuro.html):

> The Eurofighter is also fitted with an auxiliary power unit (APU) for self-starting and ground power.

See also:

- [What is the APU actually used for?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/39758/what-is-the-apu-actually-used-for)
- [Do fighter jets have an auxiliary power unit?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48083/do-fighter-jets-have-an-auxiliary-power-unit)

Comment: But what do  Kwik-E-Marts have to do with jet fighters?

Comment: *... if that is, in fact, your name ...* -- Chief Wiggum

Comment: why is it placed there like that instead of a backwards pointing nozzle somewhere else?

Comment: @user1062760 You can see the APU itself (item **71**) right below, so it would make sense to have the exhaust right next to it to save on additional tubes (and weight). I don't know why the APU is placed there, but I assume that was just a place where it could fit.